# Can we use instance variable of outer class in inner class or vice in Inner class concept in Python?

Tags: python, oop

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self,name,rollno,houseNo,area):
        self.name=name
        self.rollno=rollno
        self.address=self.Address(houseNo,area)
        print(self.name ,'and',self.rollno)

    def show(self):
        print("My name is "+ self.name+" and rollno is" ,self.rollno)

    class Address:
        def __init__(self,houseNo,area):
            print('Student\'s Address')
            self.houseNo =houseNo
            self.area=area
        def showAddress(self):
            print("My name is "+ self.name+' and address: '+self.area)
    
object1 = Students('Anubhav',18,'B-24','Lucknow')
object1.address.showAddress()
```

Here I got error at self.name in showAddress() method

Can we access instance variable of outer block in inner and vice-versa ?

The Error is as follow, I am using Python3

```
Student's Address
Anubhav and 18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FostersFC\Desktop\delete.py", line 21, in <module>
    a.showAddress()
  File "C:\Users\FostersFC\Desktop\delete.py", line 17, in showAddress
    print("My name is "+ self.name+' and address: '+self.area)
AttributeError: 'Address' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: Instance variables belong to objects, not block scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables are not scoped, they're attributes of specific objects. The `Address` object is not the same as the `Students` object that created it, so you can't use `self` to refer to the creator object.

You can pass the `Students` to the `Address` constructor, and save that for future references.

```
class Students:
    def __init__(self,name,rollno,houseNo,area):
        self.name=name
        self.rollno=rollno
        self.address=self.Address(self,houseNo,area)
        print(self.name ,'and',self.rollno)

    def show(self):
        print("My name is "+ self.name+" and rollno is" ,self.rollno)

    class Address:
        def __init__(self,student,houseNo,area):
            print('Student\'s Address')
            self.houseNo =houseNo
            self.area=area
            self.student = student
        def showAddress(self):
            print("My name is "+ self.student.name+' and address: '+self.area)
    
object1 = Students('Anubhav',18,'B-24','Lucknow')
object1.address.showAddress()
```